# Reading incorrect values from Excel using OleDbDataReader in C#.NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, automation, nunit

I'm running some test cases written in C#.NET using NUnit (this is on Visual Studio 2010). The method I'm using reads user and address data from an Excel .xls (2003) file that was provided to me by another development team. When I run the test without altering the Excel file, everything works correctly. And if I change *some* of the values in the Excel file, such as the first or last name, or street address, it still works. However, if I change the zip code field, the test fails and I get an error that says:

> "System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.DBNull' cannot be
>   converted to type 'System.Double'"

This happens even if I type in exactly the same value. In other words, if the existing zip code value is "`11111`" and I don't modify the file at all, the test works when I run it. But if I modify that field and retype "`11111`", the reader sees that as a NULL value and throws the above error. In the other rows in the spreadsheet--those that I haven't modified--the value comes back as "`11111.0d`" and everything works, so it appears that the reader is reading these values as a Double (I'm not sure why). But it won't read it that way if I type in the value myself.

One article I read suggested using `IMEX=1` in the connection string to read intermixed values as text. However, this didn't work. When I added `IMEX=1`, I got a `"Could not find installable ISAM"` message.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to setting the IMEX mode in the connection string, you might try adjusting some of the Jet engine's registry settings.

E.g., HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Microsoft/Jet/[your version]/Engines/Excel/ImportMixedTypes

Change this to Text to make that the default import for mixed types (e.g., text and numeric)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Microsoft/Jet/[your version]/Engines/Excel/TypeGuessRows

Change this to 0 to force the engine to scan all values in the column before choosing a data type (otherwise it just scans the first 8 rows).

Regarding the "Could not find installable ISAM" error. It *could* be that the path of your ISAM driver is not valid (see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209805)), but it is more likely that your connection string has an error. See [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/62ee4978-ca29-48d3-9367-6dd4ab639d2d/) for some correct examples.

Comment: Thanks! It was in fact my connection string. I added IMEX=1, but then I had to enclose all the extended properties in quotes because there was more than one. That did the trick.